# What is Mesh Independence Report?

Tags: finite-element, mesh

I am performing analysis on chassis (Static Structural) and for optimization purpose i am asked to generate MESH-INDEPENDENCE REPORT,of which i have no idea. I have tried going through research papers but couldn't find anything important.

Need a basic idea about Mesh-independence, any example would be helpful.

Comment: mesh-independence study simply shows that the solution obtained "doesn't change much" even after refining mesh any further..

Answer (score 2):

You should solve your problem on multiple, successively-refined meshes to show that the answer is not changing substantially. Many journals require this for any numerical results to demonstrate that the solution is converged.

Edited to add: See, for example, [this](http://journaltool.asme.org/templates/JFENumAccuracy.pdf) PDF from the ASME Journal of Fluids Engineering which expresses their editorial policy on the control of numerical accuracy. Item 4 on page 1 speaks to mesh independence. This journal, and most ASME numerical journals, have a similar policy for submitted numerical results. Most of the points are excellent, though I don't necessarily agree with the requirement for second-order methods (#2).